# in ifconfig.h's ifadder struct on OS X, what can I cast ifa_data to?

Tags: c++, c, macos, kernel, ifconfig

I'm getting my ifadder structs which look like this:

```
struct ifaddrs {
    struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;
    char        *ifa_name;
    unsigned int     ifa_flags;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_dstaddr;
    void        *ifa_data;
};
```

What can I cast the void *ifa_data too? I'd like to take a look inside. I'm using C/C++ (compiling with C++ compiler). I've seen people cast it to `rtnl_link_stats` but that struct doesn't seem to be a part of OS X. Any ideas?

Also bonus question here, whenever I access the sockaddr's in my ifaddrs struct, the sockaddr's sa_data member is always blank/empty. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
...
if (ifa->ifa_data != NULL) {
    struct rtnl_link_stats *stats = (rtnl_link_stats*)ifa->ifa_data;

    cout << "packets received: " << stats->rx_packets << endl;
    cout << "packets sent:     " << stats->tx_packets << endl;
    cout << "bytes received:   " << stats->rx_bytes   << endl;
    cout << "bytes sent:       " << stats->tx_bytes   << endl;
}
...
```

Comment: I need to admit I've stolen most of the code from `man getifaddrs`, nevertheless there you read `struct rtnl_link_stats *stats = ifa->ifa_data;` without explicit cast resulting in `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘rtnl_link_stats*’ [-fpermissive]`.